# Shalom Aleichem repetition on Friday night

Tags: minhag, shabbat

What are the sources that suggest to sing each stanza of Shalom Aleichem on Friday night only once as opposed to repeating them 3 times?

Comment: @Kazibácsi - check out the newer printings of the yekkish siddurim, as many of the older ones had non-yekkish mihagim in them to make them sell better in poland etc. It seems that originally it was said once, as it came from  Machzor מעגלי צדק, printed in סביוטינה year 5317 as the ending of a techinoh to say in the cemetery (http://www.moreshetashkenaz.com/life2_11.htm), but over time came to be said 3 times each in many places. I can tell you that my family (which is yekkish), for example, still says it only once

Comment: @Kazibácsi When I looked into it, it seemed that the minhag was originally to say it once, like it is in the machzor I quoted before, and then many changed it to be 3 times each, and some didn't accept the change (This also answers ezra and Double AA's questions - why should we say it 3 times if we didn't until now?) You can try taking a look at kayj, they might have something on it.

Comment: The end of the tefila over there is וְחַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא, וְרֹב עֹשֶׁר וְכָבוֹד, לְעָבְדוֹ בְּיִרְאָה וּבְאַהֲבָה. בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה הַמֶּלֶךְ הַכָּבוֹד. שָׁלוֹם לָכֶם מַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁלוֹם, שָׁלוֹם לָכֶם מַלְאֲכֵי רַחֲמִים, בּוֹאֲכֶם לְשָׁלוֹם, מַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁלוֹם, מַלְאֲכֵי הָרַחֲמִים, מַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁרֵת, בָּרוּךְ בּוֹאֲכֶם לְשָׁלוֹם (only once)

Answer (score 1):

The Yalkut Yosef (1:268:25) brought [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.268.25?lang=bi) writes:

> נהגו לומר בליל שבת פזמון ''שלום עליכם'', ויש הנוהגים לכפול כל בית ג'
>   פעמים, אך אם ממהר ללימודו, וכיוצא בזה, אין צריך לכפול.

"There are those who are accustomed to say Shalom Aleichem on shabbos night, and others have the custom to repeat it three times. However, if you must go quickly to learn or the like then you don't need to repeat it." Seemingly, the custom is really to only say it once.

Comment: The reason why I submitted this as a comment and not as an answer is that Yalkut Yosef is a very recent work, and regarding the particular case, he doesn't cite other sources. As @Uber_Chacham pointed out, this problem arised among the Yekke as well, so it's a much older and wider issue, and would be nice to have a broader explanation.

Comment: The problem is also that "must go quickly to learn or the like" applies to everyone. The Shulchan Arukh 271:1 (quoted in full), "כשיבא לביתו ימהר לאכול מיד -- when he gets home, he should hurry to eat right away". So, we all have a halakhah telling us not to dawdle because of another mitzvah.

Comment: Rav Yisrael Salanter would say Shalom Aleikhem and Eishes Chayil after hamotzi, as one of his guests might be hungry -- and many wouldn't admit it if asked. I am told this custom lasted down into R' EE Dessler's home, and for all I know may still be practiced. However, it does also solve the problem I raised in my previous comment.